# How can I create an asp.net MVC custom model validation that is working with 2 or more fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I need following attributes:

1.For example: i have 2 field. first is checkbox, second is textbox. If first control checked. second field must be `Required` attribute. first control unchecked. second control not required.

```
[Required]
public boolean showHeader{get;set;}

[IFRequired("showHeader",true)]
public string HeaderText{get;set;}
```

2.For example: i have 2 field. new password, confirmation password. Attribute must check this 2 field are equal.

```
[Required]
public string newPassword{get;set;}

[Expression("newPassword",ExpressionAttributeEnum.Equils)]
public string confirmPassword{get;set;}
```

How to create above attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using attributes.

however you can do it quite easy in your action.

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection) {
    ///do your checks here which you cant do using attributes
    ModelState.AddModelError("fieldname", "yourErrorMessage");

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ////.........
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For point 2 if you're using MVC3 use the Compare attribute

[Required]
public string newPassword{get;set;}

[Compare(]
public string confirmPassword{get;set;}

Have a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026732/asp-net-mvc-3-conditional-validation-with-dataannotations) question and answer for the first part