# Asp.net MVC 3 Conditional validation with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I are using Asp.net MVC 3, facing validation problem with dataannotations as below

We have maintained model in separate library project, model class hierarchy is like Below

```
public class EditAlternateMailingAddressModel : BaseModel
{
    public UserAddressDetails AlternateAddressDetails { get; set; }

    public List<UsState> StateList { get; set; }        
}
```

now userAddressDetails is defined like below

```
 public partial class UserAddressDetails 
    {  
      public string DeliveryLine { get; set; }
      public string Zip { get; set; }
      public bool IsDefaultMailingAddress { get; set; }        
    }
```

validation logic are defined in separate class like below

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserAddressDetailsMetaData))]
public partial class UserAddressDetails
{
    private class UserAddressDetailsMetaData
   {

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter address.")]
       public string DeliveryLine { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter city.")]
      public string City { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefaultMailingAddress { get; set; 
}
```

in edit view,  **DeliveryLine, Zip are dependent on IsDefaultMailingAddress as these fields must be provided if IsDefaultMailingAddress is true, otherwise let form to be submitted.**

for opening and partially submitting the forms we are using jQuery.

We already tried below
http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx

but these validation are fired server side, we need to make it work on client side.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833280/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-custom-client-validation ?

Answer (score 2):

You should create you own custom ValidationAttribute. If you want client validation, your attribute should implement IClientValidatable interface, and you should write custom client side validator.

**Updated**: added code samples

Implementing validator:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // your validation logic here
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    } 

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        return new[] {new CustomRequiredValidationRule (ErrorMessage)};
    }
}

public class CustomRequiredValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public RequiredIfVisibleValidationRule(string errorMessage)
    {
        ValidationType = "customRequire";
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Adding client-side validator:

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('customRequire', function (value, element) {
        // your validation logic here
        return true; // true if valid, otherwise false 
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('customRequire');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc3-custom-validation-compare-two-dates