# how to turn on/off the validation when the element is getting disabled/enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I want to disable the textbox if the checkbox is unchecked. 
View:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.prop1, new { onchange = "OnChange(this,'prop2')" })
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.prop2)
```

JavaScript handler

```
function OnChange(cb, id) 
    {
        if ($(cb).is(':checked') == false)
        {
            $('input#' + id).val('');
            $('input#' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else {
            $('input#' + id).attr('disabled', '');
            $('input#' + id).change();
        }
}
```

But there is a problem with validation messages. If prop2 is for example marked as 
"[Required]" when the textbox is disabled error message should disappear. 
And when the user check the checkbox I should enable the textbox field and turn on the validation

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check following questions:

[Asp.net MVC 3 Conditional validation with DataAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026732/asp-net-mvc-3-conditional-validation-with-dataannotations)

[MVC custom validation: compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc3-custom-validation-compare-two-dates)